# Opening a document in SharePoint 2013 requires logging in

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, office-integration

We have implemented a new install of SharePoint 2013 at my company. I've set up a web application, a site collection and a site so far. I'm setting up sites and testing them to see how SharePoint 2013 works.

But after I've logged in to SharePoint, if I go to a library where I have full control permissions, then click on a document (I uploaded there earlier), SharePoint makes me log in just to view the document (read only).

Have we configured something wrong in this implementation? How can I correct this? I never had this problem in SharePoint 2010. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Additional notes: I'm using IE 9, 32 bit version, Office Professional Plus 2010 64 bit version, and as previously mentions SharePoint Enterprise 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing we had to do was to add the sites to your trusted zone and also make some adjustments in the Windows Credential Manager. I believe its an IE issue, but too have not tracked it down. The solution we have in place works, but i also would like to find out how to fix it without this solution.

Comment: David, thank you. That fixed the problem. I appreciate your help on this. If I find a different way to fix this, I'll post it here.